# Material UI iFrame Bug Not Clickable and Volume Not Muted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, navigation, material-ui

Hi Everyone I am using a material UI card media item to display my video and I want to use the iframe component as it seems to be working better than the video one. I have 2 issues with the iframe component

1. The video autoplays with the volume on.
   I dont mind if the video autoplays but I want the volume to be on mute at first and give the user the chance to turn it up rather than the video just blast with the volume on as soon as the page loads
2. The Card is no longer clickable. As you can see I have a navlink in the code where I want the app to navigate to when a user clicks on the card but for some reason I cannot click on the card anymore.

Thanks!

```
<NavLink
   to={`/item-detail/${item.token.artAssociated.id}`}
>
 <CardMedia
   style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
   component="iframe"
   className="Media"
   src={item.token.file.videoURI}
   title={item.token.file.title}
  >
   <Typography className="MediaCaption">
     {item.token.file.title}
   </Typography>
 </CardMedia>
</NavLink>
```